# Fetch API mode: no-cors assign then function variable

Tags: javascript, apache, cors, xmlhttprequest, fetch

Hello I created this code block, and i don't know how to assign then function variable.

**Api Server:** 192.168.1.109:8085

**Nginx Client Server:** 192.168.1.137:8086, 192.168.1.109:8086

For Cors all my settings seem to be correct. I think :/.

The main responsibility is to validate and capture data when fetching data with fetch. I can not print the response data from the screen even if I succeeded. Please save me . I was stack, Today 9. day in my life :(

**httpd.conf**

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

Client Application codes for fetching data.
**device-controller.js**

```
angular
.module('interface', ['loadingStatus'])
.controller('DeviceController', DeviceController)
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

function DeviceController($scope, $http){

```
$scope.postLogin  = async function (){
    const url = 'http://192.168.1.109:8085/register/login';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("usrname", "*******");
    formData.append("passwd", "********");

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': undefined
        },
        method: 'POST',
        //mode: 'cors', // if mode no-cors 
    };

    $http.post(url, formData, config)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            toastr.success('success');
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            toastr.error('error');
        });
};
$scope.postLogin();


$scope.zwnetGetDesc = async function zwnetGetDesc(){
    await fetch('http://192.168.1.109:8085/cgi/zcgi/networks//zwnet_get_desc', {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
            'content-type': 'text/xml'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
        .then(blob => blob.text())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return error;
        });
};

$scope.zwnetGetDesc();
```

};

https://ibb.co/ePchEc [header screenshot]
https://ibb.co/jnQPSx [xml response body]

Gist Link: https://gist.github.com/umutyerebakmaz/073424a4195e75db482ac71e378e4408

Comment: I added this 2 lines

credentials: 'same-origin',
mode: 'no-cors'

its okey i see returned xml response from developer tools response and preview tab. but cant assign new variable. for view operations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had multiple details. I found it with my own talents and made it better.

**httpd.conf**

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://192.168.1.109:8086"    
Header always set Allow-Access-Credential true // outside to if module label.
```

**device.controller.js**

```
$scope.config = {
   withCredentials: true, // add all http.post 
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' } // The content-type parameter I wanted to send to the server did not overlap.
};
```

the request and response headers must be exactly the same when working with corsairs. this rule is the most important cause the failure of the slightest difference.